# AngularJS - Do I need to call $apply if no model is changed?

Tags: angularjs

Greetings Overflowers,

If I am changing an HTML native attribute (say a division's class) inside an event handler, do I need to wrap it with a call to $apply? In other words, are these native attributes watchable?

EXAMPLE:
I am doing a custom directive inside which I am modifying the element's classes for styling on certain events like mouse enter, but no modification to the scope (or model).
I am wondering if I need to surround this logic with a call to $apply just in case there is a $watch on these element's class attribute? Are these $watches possible using angularjs? My custom directive will be used by other programmers.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Any thing that Angular doesn't know about should be inside an $apply if you want bindings to be updated etc...

So no, this native attributes are not watchable if you manually change the DOM and it's not part of a user event or Angular's service event (like $http)

Comment: Sorry, I really meant: can I watch element's native attribute using angularjs?

Comment: Some of the attributes have angular directives, for others you'll have to create your own directive and handle the change. can you give an example?